# How to match a script link?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-1.0

In PowerShell, I am trying to use regex on a `<script>` block and trying to get a list of all the script tags with jQuery links. All variations like

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="..." />
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

and also with different types of quotes like single or double.

When I match it, I want to match them all (global) and then print out all the script tags (like shown above). I have this so far:

```psh
if (($contents -match "src=(.*jquery.*\.js)") -eq $true) {
    write-host "$($matches[1]) found at $($web.Url)/$url (CONTENTLINK)";
    write-host "";
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. I don't think it gets all the matches and the part is prints goes more than the script tag exactly. How can I do this?

Note: this is PowerShell 1.

Comment: Could you post an HTML snippet has all the tags you'd like to match, and then show us what you actually want the output to be, and what the output is currently? Also you say this is not powershell 2.0, so which version is it?

Comment: I also want to point out that although I may attempt to do this with regex, I would strongly recommend that you [use an HTML parser instead, as I recommend in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29930250/3905079).

Comment: I don't have the exact html snippet, as its gathering them from all around several hundred pages.

Comment: Also how can I loop through all the matches?

Comment: You could choose any one of the hundreds of files. If you can't provide what you're trying to match against, or an MVCE, or what the actual results of your current code are, then you may have trouble getting answers.

Comment: But then you only have a sample of all the types of variations.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `.*` is the go to for all people first learning regex; sadly it has side effects which ultimately cause frustration and slow regex operations.

> I don't think it gets all the matches and the part is prints goes more than the script tag exactly

One of the side effects is that it consumes everything, and I mean everything.

---

Here is the script I believe you want

`src=\x22(?=.*jquery)([^\x22]+)\x22`

Explanation

- `src=`  - Anchor text which is not captured, but it is matched. (*Found in match[0] but not match[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xb20.png)*)
- `\x22`  - Hex escape for `"` character. Easier to use in literal regex pattern.
- `(?= )` - Look ahead. Saying "I don't want to match unless I find what is in my lookahead. It stops the match if not found.
- `(?=.*jquery)` `.*jquery` somewhere there possibly exists text `.` `*` zero or more times,and the literal jquery. If "jquery" is not found, stop the processing. Otherwise continue.
- `([^\x22]+)` - We know we are going to match stuff `( )`, so any character `.` that is not `^` a quote `[^\x22]` consume it for 1 or more times `+`.
- `\x22` - Match but do not consume the final anchor text of a `"` to be complete. Also a hard stop for the `.*` processing above in the look ahead.

---

Tested with (not in Powershell but in .Net):

[image]

Two results (as matches found)

[image]