# Regex to keep only matching strings

Tags: regex, powershell

My project is to grab all of the `<a>` elements out of an HTML page for further processing.
I have a regex that matches what I want, but I just can't get PowerShell to strip out everything besides that.

My regex:

```
<a class="intranetlinktemplate".*?<\/a>
```

I tried this:

```
$x = (Get-Content $file | Out-String).Trim()
$x.Substring($x.IndexOf('<a class="intranetlinktemplate"',0)) |
    Set-Content trash.txt
$x = (Get-Content trash.txt | Out-String).Trim()
$x -replace ('</a>.*?<a class="intranetlinktemplate"','<\/a>!!!!!<a class="intranetlinktemplate"') |
    Set-Content trash.txt
```

But it just left a whole lot of miscellaneous HTML in there.

How can I edit the file so that *only* the matching strings remain?

Comment: remove the brackets around the -replace parameters. They are not supposed to be there.

Comment: Why *strip* if you can just *match*?

Comment: These questions are better if you show sample data and expected output. Instead of making us guess exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I'm not going to close this as a duplicate, but you really shouldn't be using regex to parse HTML, especially for something not-so-trivial as your example. [I strongly recommend using HTML Agility Pack as I describe in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29930250/3905079).