# Powershell Compare two XML-Files and only get the value of the change

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, compare

I wannt to compare two XML-Files in Powershell.

So my Code looks like:

```
$compareTempVar = Compare-Object $XML1 $XML2
```

So the Result is:

> InputObject
>   ....................
>   Some Text "Orginal".....
>   And some more text......
>   Some Text "Change"......
>   And even more text......
>   
>   (The Xpath is to long, to see the Change directly)

So how can i only show/export/color the Word that has been changed?
Like this Example:

Orginal | Change 
.....................................

Text before | Text after

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting the content of the files in $XML1 and $XML2 you can do this to get only lines that where changed in the original file:

```
$original = Compare-Object $XML1 $XML2 | Where-Object{ $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | ForEach-Object{ $_.InputObject }
```

To get the lines that replaced above original lines use SideIndicator "`<=`".

Comment: Okay thanks, thats very helpful but is it posible to only display the change in the Line? Example: Now i get: <path> C:\ </path>
I only wannt to display: C:\

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930191/powershell-remove-html-tags-in-string-content hope this help